# HTML scroll to bottom on a table

Tags: html, scroll

So I have a table set up that has a cutsy little javascript running in it, however it will not auto scroll to the bottom.  So my question is, how the heck do I have it automatically do it?

Answer (score -1):

IIRC something along the lines of:

```
document.body.scrollTop = tableElement.offsetTop + tableElement.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Did you define the `tableElement` at all (`var tableElement = document.getElementById('tableId');`) when you tried the above JavaScript?